How do I solve two errors appearing when I try to configure VS code to use the C/C++ compiler and run my C program codes?
I am a beginner learner of the C programming language. I just started learning this language, this year at the beginning of July. I am trying to learn the basics of C programming before going to university this September.
In order for me to run the C program, I tried to configure VS code to use the C/C++ compiler. I followed the steps on this website: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc
Everything was going well until the ‘Run helloworld.cpp’ section. When I hit run, following the instructions in the website, an error message, “ The preLaunchTask ‘C/C+ +: cl.exe build active file’ terminated with exit code -1’ ” appeared and wouldn’t let me run the code.
Then I realized, in the terminal tab below, another error is shown, ‘Link : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file ’C:\Users\60122\Desktop\projects\helloworld\helloworld.exe’ ’
Is there any way I can solve these two errors and successfully run my c program on VS code?
I would really appreciate it if you could help me with this.
Thank you

My attempts of solving the two errors
#Error 1: “ The preLaunchTask ‘C/C+ +: cl.exe build active file’ terminated with exit code -1’ ” appeared and wouldn’t let me run the code.
I searched the solutions for this error:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H2lDskr1z-0&t=32s
This video told me to delete the ‘vscode’ folder on the explorer tab in VS code. However it didn’t work.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l8g8GvqMxHc&t=50s
This video told me to go on my file -> preferences -> setting, and check the ‘run in terminal’ section, but in my VS code, there’s no such option to be checked


#Error 2: ‘Link : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file ’C:\Users\60122\Desktop\projects\helloworld\helloworld.exe’
I searched solutions for this error, and came across this:

Why does fatal error "LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Program.obj'" occur when I compile a C++ project in Visual Studio?
I think I am supposed to go to Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input, and then change the file name. However, I can’t find the ‘Configuration properties’ on my VS code.


"Linker cannot open exe file" also happens if the previous version is still running. The Windows system locks files that are executing and they cannot be replaced until they are closed.

well try this
for the first Error: "The preLaunchTask ‘C/C++: cl.exe build active file’ terminated with exit code -1"
This error typically indicates a problem with the build task configuration in VS Code. Here is how you can fix it

Open your VS Code workspace folder (where your C/C++ files are located).

Go to the .vscode folder and open the tasks.json file. If it doesn't
exist, you might need to create it. the file looks something like this
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
{
"name": "C/C++: cl.exe build and debug active file",
"type": "cppvsdbg",
"request": "launch",
"program": "${fileDirname}\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
"args": [],
"stopAtEntry": false,
"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
"environment": [],
"externalConsole": false,
"MIMode": "gdb",
"preLaunchTask": "C/C++: cl.exe build active file",
"miDebuggerPath": "gdb"
}
]
}


and for the second Error: fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Users\60122\Desktop\projects\helloworld\helloworld.exe'
This error indicates that the linker is trying to access the executable file but cannot find it. It usually happens because the build process failed before the executable could be created.
for this I would say verify the cl.exe Installation.
Note:
You may have to change few things in the json file you can find more about the taks.json file here
